# How to use make to convert files in subdirectories?

Tags: makefile

I have a directory with a bunch of subdirectories. Each subdirectory contains a traj.dat file. I want to use a Makefile to make sure that the file traj.dat gets converted to a different format, and the output file is printed in the same subdirectory as the original file.

Therefore, if I wanted to specify the names of the subdirectories, I could just use:

```
subdir1/traj.dat.xyz: subdir1/traj.dat
    my_convert subdir1/traj.dat subdir1/traj.dat.xyz
subdir2/traj.dat.xyz: subdir2/traj.dat
    my_convert subdir2/traj.dat subdir2/traj.dat.xyz
```

and so on.

How can I get the above result FOR ALL the subdirectories containing a traj.dat file, regardless of their name, without having to list them explicitly?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using GNU make, try:

```
DATFILES := $(shell find . -name traj.dat)

OUTFILES := $(addsuffix .xyz,$(DATFILES))

all: $(OUTFILES)

%.dat.xyz : %.dat
        my_convert $< $@
```

You weren't really clear what you mean by "subdirectories"; if you just mean immediate subdirectories you can use this instead of the `shell` function, which is more efficient (and works on Windows):

```
DATFILES := $(wildcard */traj.dat)
```